# Update User Information List SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

We are having a strange issue in SharePoint Online .Due to a recent change in the Organization lot of Departments names are changed and due to that the Active Directory groups are updated .When trying to share a document we noticed that the users are seeing old AD group .We had fixed this issue in our On Prem by using `Set-SPUser -Identity "DOMAIN\username" -SyncFromAD` and updating the user information list .But in our SharePoint online we couldn't run this as the Set-SPOUser doesn't have a display name as a parameter .So can you please let me know if there is a way we can do this .I had tried to delete the user from the site collection and re add which will do the trick but with that we have to re add the group to all the libraries

Comment: Did you ever find that these groups names updated? Did it just take some time?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the user information in the user information list is not updated could be the user added to site is considered an In-Active user on the site.

Refer to this article:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sposupport/2017/07/26/updating-a-user-profile-does-not-update-that-information-in-a-site-collection/

> When a user changes or adds content within a site collection,
>   SharePoint flags that user as active. For users that are set as 
>   “Active” the profile properties that are set to replicable will be
>   synced from UPA to the user information list as part of the WSSSync
>   process.

There are two ways to get a user set from inactive to active:

1. Setup an alert on the site collection for the user.
2. Share content specific with the user. Break inheritance on an item and share it with the specific user.

The active operation will take up to 24 hours before the changes are reflected in the site collection.

Comment: Thank you Joanna .I have tried to set alerts on a list and it didnt work even after 24 hrs .The difference is this is not a user but actually an AD group

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having the same issue. The objects are AD groups synched from local AD to O365 and not single user objects. They are of the group type 'MailEnabledSecurity'. So if they indeed have been flagged as "inactive" I see no way how to make the group object "active"since there's not a physical user with a user account behind it.